# Using jquery to add a "read more" link based upon another link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add a read more link in the paragraph containing rdm1 that contains the link of whatever h2 is linking to. My HTML and Javascript are below. I'm able to add read more. I'm not able to add the link of whatever h2 is. Any suggestions?

```
 <div class="divgrey">
 <h2><a href="http://www.example.com">This is a heading.</a></h2>

<p>This is some text about the heading. </p>
 <p class="rdm1"></p>
</div>
```

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.divgrey >  p.rdm1').append('<a class="rdm">Read More</a>');
    $('a.rdm').each(function () {
        var lnk = $(this).parent().siblings('a').attr('href');
        $(this).attr('href', lnk);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$( document ).ready( function() {

    $( '.rdm1' ).each( function() {
       $( this ).append( '<a href="' + $( this ).closest( '.divgrey' ).find( 'h2 a' ).attr( 'href' ) + '" class="rdm">Read More</a>' );
    });

});
```